# Is there a Stack Exchange site dedicated to music learning?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

I am a die hard SO fanatic. Completely addicted. I saw that there are Stack Exchange sites for  movies, travel, English, maths, etc.

I have just started using an acoustic guitar. So now I'm wondering whether there is a site in the network dedicated to music learning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/) site. As [is stated within their Help Center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Music: Practice & Theory** Stack Exchange is for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. If you have a question about...
>
> - practice or performance technique
> - music theory, notation, history, or composition
> - technical analysis of a specific, complete work, or well defined section thereof
> - instrument maintenance or repair
> - usage of specific music software or hardware

Your question is welcome there.

Make sure to read through [their Help Center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help) to get a decent idea of [what the site is about](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what topics you should avoid](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).